# Can I watch just one variable changing inside an array of objects in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following variable:

```
var $scope.abc = [{"a":22,"b":"x"},{"a":33,"b":"y"}];
```

Is it possible to do a watch on this and watch for just the value of the field `a` changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do a watch on this and watch for just the value of the field a changing

Sure.

If you want to watch only for value `a` you can define `ng-change` for (suppose `a` is a input) input `a`.

*HTML*

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
   <div ng-repeat="val in abc">
     <input type='text' ng-model='val.a' ng-change="onAChange(val.a)">
     <input type='text' ng-model='val.b'>
  </div>
 </div>
```

*JS*

```
$scope.onAChange = function(mod){
  console.log(mod);
};
```

Demo 1 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZhhZyBS6pt9cfWGEq0XY?p=preview)</kbd>

Other way, to `$watch` on all object `abc` and write "deep" watch, something like:

```
     $scope.$watch(function () {
       return $scope.abc[0].a;
     },
     function (newValue, oldValue) {
     if(newValue == oldValue){return;}

        console.log(newValue, oldValue);

     }, true);
```

Demo 2 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wwqs4BIrurbQryXdtpRL?p=preview)</kbd>

*As a side note:*

You don't need `var` before `$scope.abc`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about var. I will remove that, I was just trying to give an example and made a mistake. Can you explain a bit more about ng-change. I have never used that. Also I am not really sure how to code the .$watch. Thanks